# Cookie Value not available, why?

Tags: php, cookies

I have tested this on my development computer, but now I have uploaded everything to the production server and I cant read out the value of the cookie.

I think the problem lies in the Serialization and Unserialization.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['watched_ads'])){
    $expir = time()+1728000; //20 days
    $ad_arr = unserialize($_COOKIE['watched_ads']); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    $arr_elem = count($ad_arr);
    if (in_array($ad_id, $ad_arr) == FALSE){
        if ($arr_elem>10){
        array_shift($ad_arr);
        }
        $ad_arr[]=$ad_id;
        setcookie('watched_ads', serialize($ad_arr), $expir, '/');
    }
}
```

When I echo this: **count($ad_arr)** I receive the expected nr, **1** in this case, so there is a value there. But when I echo the value: **echo $ad_arr[0];** I get nothing. Completely **blank**. No text at all.

Anybody have a clue?

if you need more info about something let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was stripslashes which was needed here.

Did a stripslashes() first and it worked unserializing the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that [count](http://pt.php.net/count) returns `1` for most non-array values, including an empty string.

```
> php
<?php
echo count("");
^Z
1
```

So, to debug it, try [var_dump](http://pt.php.net/var_dump)'ing the $_COOKIE superglobal itself.

Comment: No, use the var_dump() command in php to output the contents of $_COOKIE.  http://us2.php.net/var_dump

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, that your $ad_arr is no array. You can check this with the "is_array()" function or by calling:

```
var_dump($ad_arr);
```

It sould have "array" in the output and not "string" (as Artefacto just already mentioned).

Another little tip:

If you want to store a associative array, you can use an encoded JSON String which use can save using the json_encode() gunction:

```
setcookie('watched_ads', json_encode($ad_arr), $expir, '/');
```

And loading the data you can use the opposite function json_decode():

```
$ad_arr = json_decode($_COOKIE['watched_ads'], true);
```

Adding true as a second paramter, you will get a associative array and not an object. Using the JSON format is also a good idea saving complex data within a database.

A and a last tip: "!in_array()" works just as fine as "in_array() == FALSE"